# Pyspark - Bigquery save df to hdfs

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-bigquery

I am using spark-bigquery ( spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11-0.21.1.jar ) connector to read from bigquery, I am able to read the data from bigquery and store as df.

I encounter the below error when i try to perform any type of action( write to hdfs ) or any transformation. Even df.show() gives the error at times.

using python 3.6 and spark 2.3.2. I checked the data in bigquery and there are no null columns

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col5: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col6: decimal(38,9) (nullable = true)
 |-- col7: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col8: decimal(38,9) (nullable = true)
 |-- col9: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col10: long (nullable = true)
```

`df.write.format('orc').path('/target/hdfs/path')`

Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Value at index is null
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.org.apache.arrow.vector.BigIntVector.get(BigIntVector.java:112)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.ArrowSchemaConverter$LongAccessor.getLong(ArrowSchemaConverter.java:364)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.ArrowSchemaConverter.getLong(ArrowSchemaConverter.java:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.MutableColumnarRow.getLong(MutableColumnarRow.java:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
```

Comment: Did you check null values for all the columns that are of type long?   As per the schema definition in the question all the columns could have null value.    You could also try running the query to get the distinct value of each of the column separately and see if you get null value for any of the column in the bigquery itself.

Comment: yes, there are no null values for all the columns in my source.